# dangerouslyRenderMarkup(...): Cannot render markup in a worker thread

Tags: unit-testing, testing, reactjs, mocha.js, jsdom

I saw another questions with similar issue but their solutions don't work in my case. I have properly js-dom set up:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom; // could throw
const exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];
global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
  exposedProperties.push(property);
  global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
}
});
```

and require this file before all other in my npm test launch

```
"scripts": {
      "test": "mocha --require mock-local-storage  ./src/test_helper.js --compilers js:babel-core/register,css:excluders_for_mocha_tests.js --recursive ./src/**/__test__/*_test.js --watch"
   }
```

but this doesn't help me. Interesting note: first time i launch tests there are no errors but after first saving 28 errors appear...

I read info that jasmine could use test code before test-helper was required. Maybe mocha does similar?